# Links aren't changing color when hovered over

Tags: html, css

Ok I have had these links set up for a while and decided to change the hover effect from using underline to a color change.  I'm just not understanding why the color won't change.  When I change the :hover text-decoration to underline it works but the color just says the normal link color I have set (#747474)

```
.footerList {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 9px 0 9px;
}
.footerList a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #747474;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footerList a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #747474;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footerList a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.footerList a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

<ul id="footerUlContainer">
<li class="footerList"><a href="privacy.php">Privacy Policy</a></li>
<li class="footerList"><a href="tos.php">Terms of Service</a></li>
<li class="footerList"><a href="tou.php">Terms of Use</a></li>
<li class="footerList"><a href="tou.php">Businesses</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try using !important next to color for hover

Comment: Do some debugging. Strip out all the other styles until you get the effect you want, and then start reintroducing other styles.

Comment: To be honest, this works for me - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xpc7V/).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your style is being override somewhere else, I recommend use [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), anyway try this:

```
    #footerUlContainer > .footerList a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/HSt29/1/).

Aso check out this [blog](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to get more familiar with specificity rules

Comment: thanks guys! I found out footerUlContainer was overriding my hover affect

Comment: glad you got it working :)! if you find the answer useful please consider upvoting and accepting so it remains useful for other users :)